# Using RetrieveFeedAsync to get Twitter Search Results in a Metro App

Tags: c#, twitter, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Getting familiar with Metro apps so I thought I would try my hand at some twitter stuff. The following code doesn't work.

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<TwitterItem>> Search(string term)
{
    var search = new SyndicationClient();
    var searchUri = new Uri("http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=" + term);
    //var searchUri = new Uri("http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/developers/atom.aspx");
    var results = await search.RetrieveFeedAsync(searchUri);
    return from item in results.Items
           select new TwitterItem
           {
               Text = item.Title.Text,
               CreatedAt = item.PublishedDate.DateTime,
               FromUser = item.Authors[0].Name
           };
}
```

It works if I use the windows team blog url but not the twitter url. No exceptions, it just never comes back. Tried to use fiddler but it does not intercept Metro traffic for some reason. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried it with a fixed search term? It may be that you are producing a malformed url during the concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Jon.

Please debug this code with Fiddler to ensure that you're not producing a malformed url.

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7619428/109941) for more information about using Fiddler with a Metro app.