# How to debug HTTP traffic of a Windows 8 Metro style apps using Fiddler?

Tags: http, fiddler, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm using 'HttpClient' in a Windows Metro style app and want to see the traffic using Fiddler. However, when Fiddler is active I get an exception that the app can't connect to the server. What's the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is in this article: ["Fiddler and Windows 8 Metro-style applications"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2011/09/14/fiddler-and-windows-8-metro-style-applications-https-and-private-network-capabilities.aspx).

Turns out that "connecting to Fiddler requires an Application Capability or Loopback Exemption".

Comment: As noted in that article, it requires a few other configuration changes as well.